# Laravel whereHas not filtering as expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The 2 models involved are JobRequest and StationJob. Really their relationship is oneToMany. I have a relationship set up for this $jobRequest->stationJobs().

Further to this I need a hasOne relationship latestStation, based on the same model. I need this relationship to filter my collection of JobRequests based on whether the JobRequest has a latestStation equal to a specified station.

I am expecting to get an empty list of JobRequests because I know the latestStation is equal to id 3 and I am filtering for id 2. Instead I get the jobRequest, with latestStation id 3 even though I am filtering for 2.

**Relationship**

```
public function latestStationTest()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StationJob::class)->whereNotNull('finished')->latest();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$stationId = $request->station_id;
$jobRequests = JobRequest::with(['latestStationTest'])->whereHas('latestStationTest', function($query) use ($stationId) {
            $query->where('station_id', $stationId);
        })->get();
```

**Query Result**

```
[2020-10-17 07:39:07] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `job_requests` where exists (select * from `station_jobs` where `job_requests`.`id` = `station_jobs`.`job_request_id` and `station_id` = ? and `finished` is not null)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 2,
    ),
    'time' => 1.0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `station_jobs` where `finished` is not null and `station_jobs`.`job_request_id` in (1) order by `created_at` desc',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.5,
  ),
)
```

**I've tried...**

1. Switching with() before or after whereHas makes no difference.
2. adding ->where() to with() selects the StationJob with the specified id, instead of checking if the latestStation id is equal to the specified id.

Comment: the requests seem good, so you have to check data in the DB, also you can add `DB::enableQueryLog();` before the request and `Log::info(var_export(DB::getQueryLog(), true));` after and get the raw sql to check it.

Comment: @V-K I've updated the post with Query Result, it all looks fine to me....very frustrating.